# Cython packages with the same dependency

Tags: python, cython

I have two c++ packages (A, B). Each of them will have a corresponding cython wrapper (PyA, PyB). B depends on A. PyA depends on A. PyB depends on A, B, and PyA. Will there be a conflict since both PyB and PyA depend on A?

Another related question: does the generated .so file from cython contains all the dependencies? So if I uninstall A, can I still use PyA?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: it depends on what you mean with "c++-package" (there is no such thing in C++). Is it cpp-file or static library or shared library/dll?

Comment: I meant a c++ library. Which one would be easier, static or shared?